# Set multiple variables in Powershell module and return it to main program

Tags: powershell

I have written a Powershell module which has some functions and I am setting multiple variables inside the function defined as below:

```
#
# ConfigurationHelper.psm1
#
# Global Variables
$PackageLocation = ""
$LogFilePath = ""
$LogFileName = ""
$DestinationLocation = ""
$ExcludedBinariesFiles = ""
$ExcludedBinariesFolders = ""
$IncludeTransformsFiles = ""
# end global variables
# Function to read all the config settings 
function Get-ConfigSettings {
    Write-Host "Get-ConfigSetting function is called"
    #logging configuration
    [xml] $logConfigFile = Get-Content -Path (Join-Path ((Get-Item $PSScriptRoot).Parent.FullName) "\config\GlobalConfiguration.xml")
    $LogFilePath = $logConfigFile.SelectSingleNode("/configuration/LogsPath").InnerText;
    $LogFileName = $logConfigFile.SelectSingleNode("/configuration/LogsFileName").InnerText;
    $PackageLocation = (Get-Item $PSScriptRoot).Parent.FullName

    # BinariesConfiguration
    [xml] $BinariesConfig = Get-Content -Path (Join-Path ((Get-Item $PSScriptRoot).Parent.FullName) "\config\Oakton_Environments.xml")
    $environemntNodes = $BinariesConfig.SelectNodes("//environment[@Server=$env:computername]")
    if ($environemntNodes -ne 1) {
        throw "Server configuration missing or more than one environment configuration was found for server"
    }
}
Export-ModuleMember -Function * -Variable $LogFilePath
```

In my main.ps1

```
Get-ConfigSettings

$LogFilePath #this variable is empty string
```

The variable is empty string even after the function is executed which sets the variable. I have done export member at the end of the module script. How can I return variables defined in the module?

I want to return multiple variables set at the top of the `configurationHelper.psm1`.

Comment: Define a return value and than call your function like that: $LogFilePath = Get-ConfigSettings

Comment: `$LogFilePath = ...` -> `$global:LogFilePath = ...`

Comment: The global variables works .. Just wanted to ask which is best strategy for returning variables from Module .. should I use global variables or Export-ModuleMember which doesn't seem to work in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Read and follow [`Export-ModuleMember` docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/export-modulemember):

> ```
> -Variable <String[]>
>     Specifies the variables that are exported from the script module file. 
>     Enter the **variable names**, **without a dollar sign**.
>     Wildcard characters are permitted.
> ```

Use

```
Export-ModuleMember -Function * -Variable LogFilePath
```